# Force a function to accept only object of a specific structure (in typescript / js)

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, type-safety

I know some of typescript's advantages are enabling type-safe functions -
but is it possible to ensure my function can only get objects with specific keys, or in other words - objects of specific structure ?

I know of many elegant ways to test if a nested key exists, such as [this one][1] ,
and I can of course run a small check at the beginning of my function - but the reason I'm asking this is because my function will be used by many other programmers - and I want to ensure they can understand what input they should insert just from the function's signature.

Example:

```
function printName(user){
    console.log(user.details.name); // I want to ensure details.name exist
}
```

and I would wish to have some feature like:

```
function (user : {details: {name : string}}){
    //same ...
}


[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key#answer-4034468 "this one"
```

Comment: Tried TypeScript `interface`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: I suggest running through the TS docs again. This is pretty basic. By the way, did you try the code you gave? What happened? Also, could you clarify if `details` is the only property, or one of several known in advance?

Answer (score 3):

```
interface User {
    details:{name: string}
}

function printName(user:User){
    console.log(user.details.name); // I want to ensure details.name exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the feature you desire:

```
function printName(user: { [key: string]: any, details: { [key: string]: any, name: string }}) {
    console.log(user.details.name)
}
```

Allow any properties *and* require `details` + `name`.

More legible and protected against unintentional changes:

```
// oftentimes you put the following interfaces in extra files:
interface Details {
    readonly [key: string]: any // = allow other properties than "name"*
    readonly name: string
}
interface User {
    readonly [key: string]: any // = allow other properties than "details"*
    readonly details: Details
}
// *) consider explicitly specifying them

function printName(user: User) {
    console.log(user.details.name)
}
```

And use the following code if you know other developers may call your function from plain JavaScript code (not TypeScript code):

```
function printName(user: User) {
    const name = ((user || <User>{}).details || <Details>{}).name
    if(name == void 0) {
        console.error("user name missing")
    }
    console.log(name)
}
```

[Code on TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20interface%20Details%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20name%3A%20string%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20User%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20%5Bk%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20readonly%20details%3A%20Details%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20function%20printName(user%3A%20User)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20name%20%3D%20((user%20%7C%7C%20%3CUser%3E%7B%7D).details%20%7C%7C%20%3CDetails%3E%7B%7D).name%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(name%20%3D%3D%20void%200)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.error(%22user%20name%20missing%22)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(name)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printName(%7B%7D)%20%2F%2F%20type%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printName(%7B%20details%3A%20%7B%7D%20%7D)%20%2F%2F%20type%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20printName(%7B%20details%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20%22some%20name%22%20%7D%7D))

Comment: You've assured nothing. `[key: string]: any` is a direct superset of `name: string` so it is swallowed. You've basically typed it `user: {[key: string]: any}`.

Comment: I've added a Playground link so that you can try it out.

Comment: I'll amend, in that case, `[key: string]: any` is redundant, because that's implied from the interface.

Comment: It is not redundant because there might be further properties in the object. If you explicitly specify the object's shape, you can omit `[key: string]: any`.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyof if you want to retrieve a value from a specific property, this will highlight the incorrect property name.

You can also use Object.keys to check if the property exists.

```
interface UserProps {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

export class User {
  constructor(private data: UserProps) {}

  get(propName: keyof UserProps): string | number {
    const dataKeys = Object.keys(this.data);
    if (!dataKeys.includes(propName)) {
      throw Error(`Property ${propName} does not exists on user object`);
    }
    return this.data[propName];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use interfaces in [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

```
export interface Details{
  name:string,
  age: number
}
export interface User{
  details :  {
        [key: string]: Details
    };
}

function printName(user : User){}
```

Comment: This does not work since the `Details` interface is not directly nested below `User`.